# unable to get relative path to absolute path in java

Tags: java

Im giving the path of the image to properties file and getting the path to Image class in my pdfGenerating class. like:

```
properties.load(DownloadPdf.class.getResourceAsStream("/resource.properties"));
System.out.println("--properties----"+properties);
System.out.println("-path-"+properties.getProperty("logoPath"));
//String path = properties.getProperty("logoPath");
//URL uri = Paths.get(path).toUri().toURL();
System.out.println("---path-"+properties.getProperty("logoPath"));
Image image = Image.getInstance(properties.getProperty("logoPath"));
```

Here my logopath is:

```
path----------------C:/Users/Home/Documents/workspace-gofindo/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/.....
```

But i'm getting the path in

```
Image.getInstance(properties.getProperty("logopath"));
```

like

```
C:\Users\Home\Documents\workspace-gofindo\.metadata\.plugins\org.
```

I have tried with replace and replaceAll() methods to convert '\' to '/'
again the image class converting into '\'.
How to get my absolute path which i have specified in properties file exactly into Image.getInstance() method

Comment: You know that \ *is* the correct character on windows, right? (/ is also supported as a bonus)

Comment: And \ vs / has nothing to do with absolute vs relative paths.

Comment: Which `Image` class is this?

Comment: here the Image class object taking the path like c:\Users\Home\.... and saying unable to find the specified path and raising FileNotFoundException.
When i hard code it into c:/Users/Home... Im getting the image from the specified path into the pdf document.
Im using com.itextpdf.text.Image class @Ravi Thapliyal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have remodified the way i can read the path of the file like below.

```
        // Load path of the Image from Properties file
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(
                "/resource.properties"));
        // To get the Path of the Context
        String contextPath = request.getContextPath();
        String split_path[] = contextPath.split("/");
        contextPath = request.getRealPath(split_path[0]);
        Image image = Image.getInstance(contextPath
                    + properties.getProperty("logoPath"));
        image.scaleAbsolute(120f, 60f);// image width,height
```